# Extracting URL from email inbox

Tags: python, email, url, extract

Ok there has been some confusion in what I am trying to do so I am doing this over again.  I am looking to write a script to run against my inbox that will give me the From Address, Subject, and URL in the email body.  The issue I am having is that the URL parsing of the script is pulling all URL's from the email and not just the one from the body.  Here is an example

To: Tom@mail.com

From: Joe@test.com

Subject:  Confirm you test score

Please go to the following URL to confirm your test score.  WWW.test.com/confirmation
Thanks again for your input.

Signed

Joe
(Part of Joes signature has an image)
The URL for the image is 
http://www.test.com/wp-content/uploads/_client_image/66-dcfc0fc8.png

I want my output to be

From: Joe@test.com

Subject: Confirm your test score

URL: WWW.test.com/confirmation

I get this instead

From: Joe@test.com

Subject: Confirem your test score

URL: WWW.test.com/confirmation, http://www.test.com/wp-content/uploads/_client_image/66-dcfc0fc8.png

And here is my script

```
import re
import mailbox
import urlparse

mbx=mailbox.mbox("Mail Box Path")

url_pattern = re.compile('''["']http://[^+]*?['"]''')

for k, m in mbx.iteritems():
    print "From %s\n" % m['from']
    print "Subject %s\n" % m['subject']
    print "URL %s\n" % url_pattern.findall(m.as_string())
```

Comment: Does `m.as_string()` return HTML text? If it does you could use BeautifulSoup, lxml.html to extract links.

Answer (score 0):

Signatures count as the body of the email - so you can't really separate them.

If you're sure there's only one link in the email that you care about, you could try just looking at only the first URL you match - but there isn't a (reliable) way to make sure that you're only interacting with the body of the email and not the signature as well.

[Someone even wrote a paper on this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.11.2718) - it's extremely difficult, especially when you can't control the format of the emails you're dealing with.